# how do you turn a matrix to a list in python?

Tags: python

```
nums_lst = [x for y in matrix for x in y]
```

Could anyone please help me understand what does the line `x for y in matrix for x in y` mean? matrix is of type `list[[]]`

What is `x` and what is `y` in the matrix? 
Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Your `matrix` is already a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is called list comprehension.  There’s plenty of tutorials but it’s basically flattening 3 or 4 lines of code into one. Put anyway instead of creating a list within a loop you use this special syntax. 
Here’s a good description of the technique [enter link description here](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html)

You can also use dictionary comprehensions.

Once you get used to the syntax then comprehensions do result in nice clean code.

I suggest the following learning path.  Try figure out a basic list comprehension first, for example take a list of integers and turn it into a list of squared integers. Then move onto the two dimensional element.